# C: Reading File line by line and insert data to structures

Tags: c

I need to read a text file and store the data in a structure. I have done the the part where you open the file using `FILE *fp = fopen("datafile.txt", "r")` using `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)` to read the data. My file structure is as follows

```
John is enrolled in MATH 1314
Steve is enrolled in MATH 1314


struct course {
   char name[20];
   char department[4];
   int number[4];
};

int main(void)
{
  FILE *fp;
  char* token;
  char* line[50];

  struct course student; 

  fp = fopen("input-hw04b.txt", "r");
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
  {
     token = strtok(buffer, " ");
     while (token != NULL)
     {
        /* Add structures here */
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
     }
  }
}
```

I need to store the following

- John in student.name
- MATH in student.department
- 1314 in student.number

So far this is what I have, I'm stuck on how to put this data into the structure. I pulled in the data from a text file reading it line by line then tokenized it so that I would try and put it into the structure.

Comment: Understand how to parse such strings/lines and get intended information from them in C. Search archives here or google rather than asking for code.

Comment: `char *line[50]`should be `char line[50]`. In your structure you can only store one student, if you want to store several students you need an array of your structure or a linked liste or something similar. `char department[4]` can only hold string up to a length of 3 but here eg. "MATH" is 4 chars long. You forgot to take info account the zero terminator. BTW what is `buffer` ?

Comment: I guess you meant strtok(line, " ") not strtok(buffer, " ")

Answer (score 1):

Here's some hints based on your existing code.

```
 int count = 0;
 token = strtok(buffer, " ");
 while (token != NULL)
 {
       if (count == 0)
       {
           strncpy(student.name, token, 20);
           student.name[19] = '\0'; // ensure null termination
       }
       else if (count == 1)
       {
           /* validate "is" */
           if (strcmp(token, "is") != 0)
               break;
       }
       else if (count == 2) { /*validate "enrolled"*/  }

       else if (count == 3) { /* validate "in"*/  }

       else if (count == 4)
       {
           // set the department field
       }
       else if (count == 5)
       {
           // set the number field
       }
       count++;


       token = strtok(NULL, " ");
 }
```

Of course, this example doesn't handle some robustness issues (e.g. name could be >= than 20 chars, or the string might only have 3 words in it, etc...). But should get you started...

Comment: you forgot the initial strtok(buffer, " ")

Comment: @Claptrap - that was already in the OP's original code. I didn't include that portion for brevity. I cleaned up the edited answer.

Comment: I have tried following your example but I'm getting no where

Answer (score 0):

You can parse and store strings to structure as follows

```
/*Add Structres Here*/
token = strtok(line, " ");
int j = 1;
strncpy(student.name,token,strlen(token));
while(token!=NULL)
{
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    switch(j)
    {
        case 5: strncpy(student.department,token,strlen(token));
                break;

        case 6: student.number = atoi(token);
                break;
    }
    j++;
}
j=0;

/*Your outer loop code continues*/
```

Also in your structure declaration you have given `int number[4]`(which stores 4 integers), which is wrong in your case, change it to `int number`. And also in `char* line[50]` is not correct in this context change it to `char line[50]`.